# Debug Website Locally After Enabling AAD Via Azure Portal

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have a website created in Visual Studio. I deploy it to Azure and then I enable AAD authentication via the wizard in the portal.

Now how do I debug locally and still go through the AAD login flow? I like using that portal wizard to set up AAD because it's so easy, but do I have to do all the configuration manually from VS if I want to be able to debug with AAD locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Easy Auth, I'm afraid that there's no way for that, since it's in the same context as your application. I mean, it's an IIS module.

As an alternative you can create applications under a directory in your Azure AD, for the azure webapp / local development and it will redirect to the reply URL that you've set.